# Derivative of sum of elements of array

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation, list-manipulation

I try to get derivative of sum of an array with respect to an element of the array.

$$s = \sum_{i = 1}^{3}A_{i, 1}$$
Evaluate $\frac{\partial s}{\partial A_{1,1}}$

Below is the code.

```
A = Arrays[{3, 4}]
s = sum[A[i, 1], {i, 1, 3}]
D[s, A[1, 1]]
```

That gives 0 instead of 1. What went wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: sum should be `Sum`

Comment: Thanks. That works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an array with [`Array`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Array.html)

```
A = Array[a, {3, 4}]

(* {{a[1, 1], a[1, 2], a[1, 3], a[1, 4]}, {a[2, 1], a[2, 2], a[2, 3], 
  a[2, 4]}, {a[3, 1], a[3, 2], a[3, 3], a[3, 4]}} *)
```

Like all built-in commands, [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html) must start with a capital letter. And [`Part`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) uses double square brackets

```
s = Sum[A[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 3}]

(* a[1, 1] + a[2, 1] + a[3, 1] *)

s = A[[All, 1]] // Total

(* a[1, 1] + a[2, 1] + a[3, 1] *)
```

Or for the indexed variable

```
s = Sum[a[i, 1], {i, 1, 3}]

(* a[1, 1] + a[2, 1] + a[3, 1] *)
```

Similarly,

```
D[s, A[[1, 1]]]

(* 1 *)

D[s, a[1, 1]]

(* 1 *)
```